# Azure Python CLI: launch script with run-command invoke fails when passing the script file with @ but not with inline commands

Tags: python, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have a project designed to launch PowerShell scripts to run in Azure VMs using AZCLI with the following structure

```
* /myAPP
  * /main (package)
    * main.py
    * /util (package)
        * auth.py
        * launchscript.py
        * testscript.ps1
```

main.py calls class from launchscript.py in order to launch the script itself.

1. If I launch the PS script to a VM using the inline option it works

```
import azure.cli.core as azclicor
output = azclicor.get_default_cli().invoke(['vm','run-command','invoke','--command-id','RunPowerShellScript','--name','VM1','-g','VM_RG','--scripts','hostname'])
```

2. When I launch it with the script that's inside the module it fails

```
import azure.cli.core as azclicor
output = azclicor.get_default_cli().invoke(['vm','run-command','invoke','--command-id','RunPowerShellScript','--name','VM1','-g','VM_RG','--scripts','`@testscript.ps1'])
```

ERROR: "*The term 'testscript.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*" just as if I used another name of a script that does not exists. So it seems its failing to find the script, even though its on the same folder than the module calling it.

However, in another test project I have:

```
* /myAPPTest
  * /util (package)
    * main.py
    * auth.py
    * launchscript.py
    * testscript.ps1
```

The method using @ works, with exactly the same code. I think the issue might be with the modules and how Python loads them, but I am really confused and don't know what to test in order to make the first (more nested) version work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

My project structure

```
  * /cli (package)
    * main.py
    * /util (package)
        * test.ps1
```

My powershell file

```
Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath C:\Process.txt
```

my code

```
import azure.cli.core as azclicor
import os.path as path

t=path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))+'/until/test.ps1'
file_path=t.replace('\\','/')

output = azclicor.get_default_cli().invoke(['vm','run-command','invoke','--command-id',
        'RunPowerShellScript','--name','worker','-g','worker_group',
        '--scripts', f'@{file_path}'])
```

Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: The not recognized error is gone, using the code you provided, but I'm getting `\nUnrecognized token in source text.\n + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx \n ception\n + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken\n` it seems something is not quite right yet. I don't think thats in the script itself as the file only contains the alias "Hostname" for testing pruposes

Comment: @AbianG It seams that your PowerShell script has some issue

Comment: I tested using the same command you use in your example, and i still get the same error. Is there any way to test if its an script issue or the way the file is being passed?

Comment: @AbianG you can add `--debug` at the end of the command.

Comment: After debugging I found some issues with the path I was using. Your answers worked perfectly. Many thanks for the help!! :)